# Do making multiple local requests slow down Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm curious... When developing a website the general rule of thumb is to concatenate common files like JS and CSS to reduce the number of requests when your page loads, but does this apply to Chrome Extensions - or any browser extensions for that matter - that are requesting local assets (stored within the extension bundle)?

Let's say I wanted to load in a couple fonts, icons, and a few extra stylesheets. Typically I would base64 the icons and combine them with my "few extra stylesheets" to create one larger stylesheet to call, but in a Chrome Extension since everything is stored within the user's computer/the extension's bundle, is it going to make a discernible page-load difference if I requested them all separately?

Thanks!

Comment: Go profile, take a look at the Network / timeline tab of the developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it wont make any discernible difference.
The round trip from browser to disk is neglegible compared to a request on the internet, even millions of times slower for a solid state disk.